# Apache Httpd 2.4 Rewrite Rule to return 301 redirect, but returns 302

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite, httpd, apache2

I have two different examples of where Apache Httpd 2.4 on Centos7 is configured to perform redirects with the R=301 flag, but they are actually returning 302 redirects. One is an extremely simple case, just redirecting http to https. Here is the extent of the rewrite rules:

```
<VirtualHost ...>
  ... other content ...
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Why is this returning a 302 redirect instead of 301?

```
# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   example.com (/etc/httpd/sites- 
enabled/example.com.conf:5)
*:443                  example.com (/etc/httpd/sites- 
enabled/example.com.conf:23)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: "Why is this returning a 302" - it's not; _something else_ is. The fact that you are checking the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header implies you are behind a front-end proxy that handles your SSL - is that the case? Although your log appears to suggest otherwise? "two different examples of where" - where is the _other_ example?

Comment: @MrWhite - The final solution is behind a load balancer that provides SSL termination. However, I am just curl(ing) localhost on the server and seeing the 302 response. Nothing else is in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not using the appropriate hostname for curl. The rewrite rule is triggered on condition of matching hostname *example.com*. If you are just using `curl http://localhost` then httpd gets the hostname "localhost" and the rule does not match. Instead use the curl command with a --proxy argument pointing at localhost (be sure to specify the port number!) and the url argument matching the expected host name. Like this:

```
curl --proxy localhost:80 http://example.com
```

Comment: So, "something else" _is_ triggering the 302. (In a virtual host context, you wouldn't normally _need_ to check the `Host` header.) "Your problem..." - you are addressing yourself in the 3rd person?